# Can't change Azure web site from Basic to Shared

Tags: azure

I have some Azure web sites that have the Web Hosting Plan Mode set to "Basic".

I'm trying to change them to "Shared".

However, when saving the new Plan Mode, it fails with the error message: `Cannot update the site '____' because it uses AutoHeal feature which is not allowed in the target compute mode.`

That's fine, I don't need the "AutoHeal" feature on these sites.

But, how can that be turned off?

I don't see any such setting in either version of the portal.  There is the "Always On" configuration, but that is turned off. I've seen mention that it uses settings in the web.config file, but each of the sites have the same web.config, and only one of them is listed in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in Azure.  It is now fixed, and I was able to change the Hosting Plan Mode.

See [Cannot scale down to Shared](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e626dd67-9e4f-4c77-8115-cfbab65dec0a/cannot-scale-down-to-shared-error-says-due-to-auto-heal-feature).

Answer (score 0):

Always On is not going to affect it. Number of instances and their size might. Have a look at this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/d21727c3-df8b-4b5c-acb9-8a890538eb84/unable-to-downgrade-azure-basic-website-to-free-mode-because-autoheal-enabled-error?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

I was able to create a website with standard or basic hosting plan, scale it up and out, and then switch to shared hosting. Sometimes there are glitches, so you might need to open a support ticket with MSFT.